# Android Studio: How to add filter on a recyclerview and how to implement it

Tags: java, android

```
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            dbList = itemListCopy;

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                List<DbItemModel> filterList = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < dbList.size(); i++) {
                    String str = (dbList.get(i).getItemDetails().toUpperCase()) + " " +
                            (dbList.get(i).getGroupName().toUpperCase()) + " " +
                            (dbList.get(i).getItemName().toUpperCase()) + " ";
                    if (str.contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        filterList.add(dbList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                dbList = filterList;
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = itemListCopy.size();
                results.values = itemListCopy;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
            dbList = (List<DbItemModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

I want to add filter on my recyclerview and use it for search function. Pls. help me and if you can make it simple. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 implement Filterable interface to your adapter and implement its method

eg :

```
 public class MyAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable{
  // Other code 

   }
```

Step 2 create a class which extends Filter

eg :

```
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
  FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
  contactList = contactsListCopy;
// Replace with your own logic 
  if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
    List<Contacts> filterList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
      if ((contactList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
          .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
        filterList.add(contactList.get(i));
      }
    }
    contactList = filterList;
    results.count = filterList.size();
    results.values = filterList;
  } else {
    results.count = contactsListCopy.size();
    results.values = contactsListCopy;
  }
  return results;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
  contactList = (List<Contacts>) results.values;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Step 3: For simplicity add

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
  android:id="@+id/search"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

in the fragment/activity layout above recycler view

Step 4 in your activity/Fragment implement  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener and initialize view

```
 SearchView sv = (SearchView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.search);
 sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 sv.setQueryHint("Search Here");
sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

Step 5: Implement all the method

Step 6  Update adapter like this

```
      @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Just want to try your code in my existing activity. and i want a collapsible search button located in action bar menu to do the search/filter on my recyclerview.. What would be the code for it?

Comment: Sorry for asking this (bec. Im just starting to code using android and java), where should I put/type the class ValueFilter? should I create a new java class file?

Comment: You can out that in adapter class only

Comment: Please explain contactList and contactListCopy. Do I need to declare some class?

Comment: No thats just the logic for my filter . You need to have your own implementation there

Comment: what type of variable is contactList and contactListCopy? Is it an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes in my case they are arraylist

Comment: Here is my code. Please take a look if I'm on a right path.

Comment: I posted my code in the main question. Pleasse take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: No issues did the answer helped? if yes please accept it

Comment: Wait. Im having some problem. getFilter gets red (error) on my MainActivity.
 and in my Adapter it says on the class declaration, "Class 'RecyclerItemAdapter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getFilter()' in 'Filterable'". how is that? : (

Comment: is that made public

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: 'getFilter() method is public or not?

Comment: yes it's inside a public. I will post my code in MainActivity. See the code of it in my own answer.